# Spring Boot integration testing with Async Jobs and Request Scope beans

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, testing

the problem I'm facing consists of 3 factors:

- Spring Boot integration testing with Maven & JUnit
- A request scope bean within the context of the application
- An async job that runs on app start.

The problem occurs **on testing only**, the application runs as intended when building without tests.

Simplified application flow:

- **On Spring Boot startup**, an **async** job concurrently fetches data from Data Source and stores it on cache (Guava CacheLoader)
- When user requests this data, intercept the request, authenticate header tokens, store user info in **Request scope** bean and continue.
- Fetch data from Cache and return to user.

The error I get when trying to run Maven Test:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.requestBean': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

**Important note & clue to solving this**: When the controller fetches directly from DAO (Data Source), the tests pass!!! Only when it fetches from Guava Cache it fails.

Simplified code:

```
/* Part of the controller: */
 @Autowired AsyncCacheService cacheService;
 @RequestMapping("/resellers")
 public HashMap<String, Reseller> getAllResellers() throws Exception {
   return cacheService.getAllResellers();
   //When I switch to get directly from DAO below, tests pass.
   //return partnerDao.getAllResellers(); <-- get directly from DAO.
 }




/* The service which the controller calls */
@Service
public class AsyncCacheService {
  private LoadingCache<String, List<Reseller>> resellersCache;
  public AsyncCacheService() {

    resellersCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, 
    HashMap<String, Reseller>>() {
      public HashMap<String, Reseller> load(String key) throws Exception {
        return partnerDao.getAllResellers();
      }
    });
  }
  @PostConstruct
  private void refreshCache() {
    /* Refresh cache concurrently */    
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                () -> resellersCache.refresh(this.getClass().toString()), 0, 
                cacheRefreshTimeInterval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
  /* Return resellers from cache */
  public HashMap<String, Reseller> getAllResellers() {
    return resellersCache.getUnchecked(this.getClass().toString());
  }
}
```

Interceptor code is straight forward:

```
@Component
public class AuthInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
  private @Autowired RequestBean requestBean;
  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
       response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    //Verify request and requestBean.set(email, ip, foo)
  }
}
```

How we instantiate request bean:

```
@Bean
@RequestScope
public RequestBean requestBean() {
    return new RequestBean();
}
```

And finally, the tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
tester {
  @Test
  public void allResellersSizeTest() throws Exception {

    //MvcResult r = 

      mockMvc.perform(get("/api/resellers").header(authHeaderName, jwtToken))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());//.andReturn();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a proper fix, so I ended up delaying the async jobs a couple of seconds after server start:

```
 @PostConstruct
  private void refreshCache() {
    /* Refresh cache concurrently */    
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                () -> resellersCache.refresh(this.getClass().toString()), 33,
                cacheRefreshTimeInterval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```